# What is the greatest advantage of SO careers CV?

Tags: discussion, jobs, cv

I logged into Stack Overflow Careers and started my CV. However I do not understand what is supposed to be better than similar solutions such as LinkedIn.

I find LinkedIn much more convenient. I find SO quite young yet and lacking the features that could overthrown LinkedIn as a public cv repository.

So far I see no added value. I would rather provide just a link to my stackoverflow user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the only way you can get [hired](https://stackoverflow.com/about/hiring) at SO.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed your use of the word "public."  By definition, Stack Overflow Careers (at least the actual job searching part of it) is *not* public.  You have to pay a fee to join the service.

However, creating a CV is free and, most likely, no better than LinkedIn or any of a hundred other services.  The real benefit comes from paying the fee and joining a small pool of committed developers looking for jobs.

In fact, only creating the free CV may be less helpful than other services, at least for right now, since StackOverflow's footprint in the job-search area is very small.  If you are going to pay the fee to post your CV, however, it looks to be much more useful (read: likely to find a challenging, productive job or worthwhile employee).

Answer (score 1):

One thing I like about it is that it isn't a generic CV service but tailored to programming - with fields like *First Computer* or *Favorite Editor* and the embedded SO profile. Makes it feel more personal in a way.